# DynamicData not working as expected when using an ImmutableList

Tags: c#, mstest, immutablelist

Consider the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new object[]
        {
            "hello",
            ImmutableList<string>.Empty.AddRange(
                new List<string>()
                {
                    "one",
                    "two"
                }
            )
        };
    }
}

[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(TestData))]
public void Sandbox(string myString, ImmutableList<string> myList)
{
    var sameListInstantiatedHere = ImmutableList<string>.Empty.AddRange(
        new List<string>()
        {
            "one",
            "two"
        }
    );

    sameListInstantiatedHere.Count.Should().Be(2);

    myString.Should().Be("hello");
    myList.Count.Should().Be(2);
}
```

I get this error:

> Expected myList.Count to be 2, but found 0 (difference of -2).

I really can't figure out why `myList` has only zero items. Note how I even use the same code to instantiate it in my `Sandbox` method and how `sameListInstantiatedHere.Count.Should().Be(2);` passes the test, while `myList.Count.Should().Be(2);` does not.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very unexpected behaviour indeed which can be fixed by applying this attribute:

```
[assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)]
```

It seems that this behaviour is caused by MSTest discovery mechanism change [introduced in 2.2.6](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/mstest-passing-readonly-struct-as-dynamicdata-fail/1620466#TPIN-N1690790) which by default (without the above attribute) requires the test case data to be serialisable which seems to be the culprit here (note: it does work as expected with `List<>` but not with `ImmutableList<>`).

Yet another way to fix it is to switch to [xUnit](https://xunit.net) which does work as expected out of the box:

```
public class UnitTest
{
    public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[]
            {
                "hello",
                ImmutableList.Create("one", "two")
            };
        }
    }    

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(TestData))]
    public void Sandbox(string myString, ImmutableList<string> myList)
    {
        myString.Should().Be("hello");
        myList.Count.Should().Be(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, using `DuringExecution` worked, but as a side effect this won't give single "subentries" per dynamic data test values. I switched to List to work around this. Do you know how one can check if a class is serializable? Wondering if ImmutableList really doesn't support serialization. BTW, great XUnit sample, but same issue as with DuringExecution` on MSTest: no single "subentries" when having mutiple yield returns. (with subentries I mean this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76982547/testexplorer-missing-single-test-data-entries-when-using-dynamicdata-with-comple)

Comment: No, `Immutable*` collections [are not serializable](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14395#issuecomment-604112740)